# write text on a Line in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, label

i am trying to create something like this:
[image]

so i wrote this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="alphatrial.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#ffc40c">

    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="ISC - Alpha" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="MyAwesomeCustomFont" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,50,20,0" />
        <Line Stroke="black" X1="0"  X2="340" StrokeThickness="2" />

        <Label Text="App" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="MyAwesomeCustomFont" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

but i get this
[image]
i can't manage to get the words on the line directly. i don't want this space between the words and the line. what should i do?
thanks in advance

Comment: StackLayout has a default Spacing value of 6.

Comment: oh okay, got it. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account also the Padding and the Margins of the label.As for the layout spacing
If that is not enough for you, you can even set a negative margin to overlap the components

Comment: thanks a lot. setting top and bottom margin values of the labels to negative worked.